# Progress dialog does not dismiss if i scroll faster in my listview

Tags: android, scroll

If i scroll faster my `progress dialog` does not dismiss and stays on the screen for infinite time.Any help? Tried a lot of things but it still remains there. Is there any way i can dismiss it. I guess the `dismis()` function is not called in `onPostExecute()`.

***Code***

```
package com.company.napp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare Variables
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist1;
    int page=1;
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String TITLE = "title";
    static String ADDRESS = "address";
    static String COUNTRY = "country";
    static String IMAGE = "image";
    static String SERVICETYPE="serviceType";
    static String PHNUM="phnum";
    static String DESCRIPTION="description";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        listview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int threshold = 1;

                int count = listview.getCount();
                System.out.println("\nLast visible = "+listview.getLastVisiblePosition()+"\nCount = "+count);
                if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    if (listview.getLastVisiblePosition()+1 > count-1) {
                        // Execute LoadMoreDataTask AsyncTask

                        new LoadMoreDataTask().execute();

                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                 int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

    }


    //DownloadJSON AsyncTask

    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Napp");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
            mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            //mProgressDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://54.169.88.65/events/TA/JsonTA.php?page=1");

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("Contacts");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    String t, a, d, s;
                    t = jsonobject.getString("title");
                    t = t.replaceAll("\\n", "");
                    //t="\n"+t;
                    a = jsonobject.getString("address");
                    a = a.replaceAll("\\n", "");
                    d = jsonobject.getString("description");
                    d = d.replaceAll("\\n", "");
                    s = jsonobject.getString("serviceType");
                    s = s.replaceAll("\\n", "");
                    //s=s+"\n";

                    map.put("title", t);
                    map.put("address", a);
                    map.put("country", jsonobject.getString("country"));
                    map.put("image", jsonobject.getString("image"));
                    map.put("serviceType", s);
                    map.put("phnum", jsonobject.getString("phnum"));
                    map.put("description", d);
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();


        }
    }
        private class LoadMoreDataTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Create a progressdialog
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                // Set progressdialog title
                //mProgressDialog.setTitle("Napp");
                // Set progressdialog message
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                //Show progressdialog
               mProgressDialog.show();
                mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                //mProgressDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // Create an array

                page+=1;
                //arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
                jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://54.169.88.65/events/TA/JsonTA.php?page="+page);

                try {
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
                    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("Contacts");
                    arraylist1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects
                        String t,a,d,s;
                        t=jsonobject.getString("title");
                        t=t.replaceAll("\\n", "");
                        //t="\n"+t;
                        a=jsonobject.getString("address");
                        a=a.replaceAll("\\n","");
                        d=jsonobject.getString("description");
                        d=d.replaceAll("\\n","");
                        s=jsonobject.getString("serviceType");
                        s=s.replaceAll("\\n","");
                        //s=s+"\n";

                        map.put("title",t);
                        map.put("address",a);
                        map.put("country", jsonobject.getString("country"));
                        map.put("image", jsonobject.getString("image"));
                        map.put("serviceType",s);
                        map.put("phnum",jsonobject.getString("phnum"));
                        map.put("description",d);
                        // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                        arraylist1.add(map);

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.addAll(arraylist1);
                //locate listview last item
                int position =listview.getLastVisiblePosition();
                adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);


                // Set the adapter to the ListView
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);

                //show the lastest retrieved results on the top
                listview.setSelectionFromTop(position,0);


                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                // Close the progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();



            }





        }




    }
```

Comment: Try to mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); to true then when you click on outside your ProgressDialog canceled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like before the first call of the Asynctask is completed, you are making a call to it again. So the best solution would be to not create a progress dialog everytime you create the task but check if the dialog is already running and handle accordingly. There are multiple instances of the progress dialog getting created and all are not being destroyed

Comment: I solved the problem. The issue was same as you pointed out. I created a boolean variable 'b' which is initially set to true.I check it everytime before calling the asynctask. When i call an asynctask i set b to false in onPreExecute() and i again set it to true only in the last line of onPostexecute(). This way my new asynctask only gets called when the previous finishes completely.

Comment: Hey Vicky, thats great. If you think my answer solved your problem, upvote it and mark it as an accepted answer. Thanks :)